# New reason to close a question: "Abandoned question"

Tags: feature-request

There are quite some questions we can not answer, because the OP never returns to provide the necessary MWE or at least information. Well, this one e.g.: [forcing a footnote to split across mutiple pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/255873/4736)

I'd like to close such questions a week later after somebody requested more info without the OP logging into tex.stackexchange. Let's say: "Abandoned question -- neither the person, who asked the question, nor anybody else, provided requested information within a week, and the question has no answer."

Comment: We (TeX-sx) cannot extend the core close reasons. What we can do is describe such questions as 'off topic'.

Comment: Thank you! See here now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261326/202073

Comment: You've taken a risk going to the main meta :-) The approach on TeX-sx is somewhat variant from that of the 'main' site!

Comment: We also use 'unclear' here, BTW

Comment: And received already a ridiculous response too :)

Comment: @NormalHuman If the review system wasn't in place. I would agree. Now it's a matter of clicking buttons without reading the questions or comments or anything at all. The main point is that we don't operate as they do on SO. And closing a question immediately is still ridiculous for a new user who doesn't know what the residents fancy as a good question. But I don't care what happens there. Here I do.

Comment: @JosephWright `»You've taken a risk going to the main meta :-) The approach on TeX-sx is somewhat variant from that of the 'main' site!«` Yes, but since you gave me some hints about the business model of the whole site I know that I don't have to care. By the way, it is much more fun to read and discuss here since I met a bunch of regulars at the tug meeting and now have an impression who is who. Regarding my question: Closing abandoned questions as unclear is ok, as long as we do not offend people by closing to fast. My rules of thumb: When in doubt, don't close. Wait some days.

Comment: There are very old questions that still get answers eventually. I feel like we should wait months, rather than weeks, before closing as unclear. But I do think closing as unclear is the right thing in such a case.

Comment: @AndrewCashner If they really answer the question, how can it have been unclear? I thought the question here concerned questions which really can't be answered without just inventing stuff and arbitrarily filling in the details omitted by the OP. I don't know how long is reasonable to wait but if the question is both abandoned and unclear, hoping somebody will answer is a pipe dream. On the other hand, if the question *is* clear, why close it even if it is unanswered for years? (Unless it is off-topic or a duplicate or whatever.)

Comment: (cont) Sometimes old questions are closed just because we can't answer them. I don't think they should be closed in those cases. That is, just because there is (currently) no solution, doesn't mean the question is a bad one.

Comment: @cfr I see your point. If the question is unclear (missing necessary info from OP) and there is no action to clarify it, then it benefits no one and should be closed as unclear. But for questions that are old but clear, we should leave them open.

Comment: @cfr There are some very good old questions which are not closed but have no answers: as you note it's entirely possible for this to occur and they should be left open. On questions that need more info to answer, original consensus was that the OP gets a week or two to fill in the detail. To me that's felt like a sensible balance: questions get answered, improved or closed but letting the OP have a chance to improve them. (Of course, as a mod I don't get to vote to close so it's a bit academic.)